# Website-Navigation disabled on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, z-index

I have a very rare problem on iOS (iphone).
i developed the site yolieva.de with a videoclip which also runs on ios. but it plays in the background because on top is the navigation with z-index. but it is not accessible from ios. kind of disabled because of the videoclip. you may want to try it with an iphone and you see you cant click through the site…
how to solve this? i want to keep the navigation above the video

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with how iOS deals with the videoclip, so I am not sure that you can do anything about it directly.

Why don't you make the div containing the flash player (id player) smaller on the iphone?

In fact, on the iphone your flash video is not shown in place, there is anyway a change of view, so there is no need of having it full screen either. Of course, you should make your flash player div smaller only for iOS, not other browsers, where it is fine that it is full screen...